# How to store variable data in other variable and parse it

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a way, how set data from var title, to other data ( var t ), and see result in page source.
Now i have:

```
// example: home
var title = document.title;

var t = title;
```

Now, in souce view, var title = document.title and var t also.

How can i parse this code, and see document.title returned value ?

Thanks for explain.

With this code:
    
    var title = document.title

i Want to see in source code of browser:
var title = 'title of page being viewed' instead of var title = document.title

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't how JavaScript works.

It is a dynamic scripting language that runs in the web browser and affects that visitors page only.

When you choose View Source you are looking at the underlying code before it is executed.

If you want to pull information from another source then you need to look into either:

- Screen scraping
- Web services

Screen scraping is the process of downloading a webpage and then looking inside of it to pull information out. This can be messy if the website changes the layout of the page or the content is badly formatted.

A better way to provide information to 3rd party sources is to create a web service. This gives you an API which you can query and then you can return data in a computer readable format.

Answer (score -1):

You mean that display the value of variable on your browser?

Just use this code:
`console.dir(t);`

And you can see the result on console panel.

Comment: I want to see value of var t in source code, not console.
Some external JS code need to retrieve value of var t, but var t in source code is 'document.title' not desired page title.